# Application log analysis from Kibana

Tags: kibana

In Kibana dashboard how we can see only some specific fields in view. While we filter out records depending on condition we can see there are multiple fields appearing in view which is difficult in analyse and visualize for exact error. Its better if we can see only specific fields like maybe like fields logs: and not interested with other fields. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create different filters of the log data that you are pushing into your ES indexes and when that data is visualized in Kibana you can select only the data concerned with useful filters only.